# Sorting arrays of object that have optional value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, option-type

I am trying to sort an array of a custom struct by an attribute `currentPeriod`, this attribute depends on an optional type called `scoreboard`, this is how I am attempting to sort:

```
var newValue = value.sorted(by: {$0.scoreboard?.currentPeriod > $1.scoreboard?.currentPeriod})
```

But is giving me errors since you cannot compare optionals, given an array of `LSGame` how can I sort it so that elements without scoreboard end up last in the array? For example a list of games based on currentPeriod should look like: `9,7,4,1,nil,nil`

Here are the structs

```
public struct LSGame: Codable {
    public var scoreboard: LSScoreboard?
}

public struct LSScoreboard: Codable {
    public var currentPeriod: Int
}
```

Comment: Use compactMap to remove optional Values. ( it will remove all values that gives nil on unwrapping), and then sort your array.

Comment: @TusharSharma Look at the expected result, nothing should be removed so compactMap is not the solution here.

Comment: ahh I see my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this -

```
let values: [LSGame] = [
            LSGame(scoreboard: nil),
            LSGame(scoreboard: LSScoreboard(currentPeriod: 9)),
            LSGame(scoreboard: nil),
            LSGame(scoreboard: LSScoreboard(currentPeriod: 1)),
            LSGame(scoreboard: LSScoreboard(currentPeriod: 7)),
            LSGame(scoreboard: LSScoreboard(currentPeriod: 4)),
        ]

var sorted = values.sorted(by: { ($0.scoreboard?.currentPeriod ?? 0) > ($1.scoreboard?.currentPeriod ?? 0) })
```

Output -

```
(lldb) po sorted
▿ 6 elements
  ▿ 0 : LSGame
    ▿ scoreboard : Optional<LSScoreboard>
      ▿ some : LSScoreboard
        - currentPeriod : 9
  ▿ 1 : LSGame
    ▿ scoreboard : Optional<LSScoreboard>
      ▿ some : LSScoreboard
        - currentPeriod : 7
  ▿ 2 : LSGame
    ▿ scoreboard : Optional<LSScoreboard>
      ▿ some : LSScoreboard
        - currentPeriod : 4
  ▿ 3 : LSGame
    ▿ scoreboard : Optional<LSScoreboard>
      ▿ some : LSScoreboard
        - currentPeriod : 1
  ▿ 4 : LSGame
    - scoreboard : nil
  ▿ 5 : LSGame
    - scoreboard : nil
```

Comment: Yup this is how it should be done. I was using my knee caps to think instead of my brain

Comment: @ShedSports Note that in the duplicate question (linked above) Int.min is used rather than 0 which can make a difference if 0 is a valid value for the scoreboard.currentPeriod property.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the additional info, in this case 0 would be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if let scoreboard = scoreboard {
      var newValue = value.sorted(by: {$0.scoreboard?.currentPeriod > $1.scoreboard?.currentPeriod})

}
```

Comment: scoreboard isn't accessible on it's own like that. I have an array of ```LSGame``` that I want to sort

Comment: instead of scoreboard use LSGame.scoreboard or whatever the instance you are taking from LSGame, let's suppose you have "var lsGame: LSGame!" then you can say "if let scoreboard = lsGame.scoreboard"